# How to send the dynamic values from current request body

Tags: groovy, jmeter-5.0

I am currently using Jmeter tool for my application performance testing. I have situation here and i tried in many ways. As i am new, i didnt get solution.

Could you please help me.

Situation:

Agent1 receiving call when customer dial to a channel. Jmeter recorded the below as request.

```
5|0|21|https://d50.eng.domain.com:1050/newgenmashup/v1/mashup/|1D4E8B05B21570719C10066C4E15360C|com.contactual.client.SFService|triggerEvent|java.lang.String|com.contactual.client.model.GenericXmlData|java.util.TreeMap|tenant~~pagent2|com.contactual.client.model.GenericXmlData/2918165779||353-726-6515|no|offered|PHONE|in|563|PavanInboundQueue|1|465| <UserData>
<param name = "@pri"><![CDATA[100]]></param>
<param name="callingName"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="cha"><![CDATA[3537266515]]></param>
<param name="channelName"><![CDATA[353-726-6515]]></param>
<param name="cnt"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="con"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="med"><![CDATA[T]]></param>
<param name="otim"><![CDATA[1550070210]]></param>
<param name="pho"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="phoneNum"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="priority"><![CDATA[50]]></param>
<param name="que"><![CDATA[vcclondon~~queue~~phone~~563]]></param>
<param name="queueDirection"><![CDATA[in]]></param>
<param name="tenantName"><![CDATA[vcclondon]]></param>
<param name="tenantRecServer"><![CDATA[d50]]></param>
<param name="tenantSkillName"><![CDATA[PavanInboundQueue]]></param>
<param name="tim"><![CDATA[1550070210]]></param>
<param name="tok"><![CDATA[465]]></param>
<param name="queuedTime"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="ani"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="interaction_guid"><![CDATA[int-168e76257e3-r5tEbRqwNR7hBd7jmuvwnsxG9-phone-00-vcclondon]]></param>
<param name="transaction_id"><![CDATA[465]]></param>
<param name="notes"><![CDATA[]]></param>
<param name="callbackTimeMs"><![CDATA[]]></param>
<param name="ctl_userdata"><![CDATA[[doNotCallSelected\!false][donotcallSelected\!false]]]></param>
</UserData>|java.util.TreeMap/1575826026|1|2|3|4|3|5|6|7|8|9|0|0|0|0|10|0|0|0|10|0|11|0|12|0|13|10|0|10|1|0|0|0|14|15|16|17|18|10|10|0|19|20|21|0|0|
```

All are dynamically generated values. No values comes from previous request. I would like to store all dynamic values whenever customer call to a channel. And pass the same values dynamically to the current request only. Can you please help me to do that.